# TensorFlow ImportError

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been trying to get TensorFlow to work on my MacBook Pro for the last week, and I keep getting the following ImportError (entire stack trace included for clarity):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mbillman/Desktop/ML/Python_NNs/tensorFlow.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Do you need the GPU version of TensorFlow (i.e. have an NVIDIA GPU)? If not, installing the CPU version will work around this error. If you do want the GPU version, is CUDA 8 installed?

Comment: Yes, I do have an NVIDIA GPU. Cuda 8 is installed in /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0

Comment: @AllenLavoie, I am also using Python 3.6 thru Anaconda. Since posting this I have wiped my hard drive, reinstalled Mac OS X Sierra for a clean slate, and installed CUDA and Anaconda. I'll have to re-download TensorFlow.

Comment: According to this answer, https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/277401 you would need an external monitor plugged into the eGPU in order for the MacBook Pro to even use it. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I think it's got to be an issue with GPU compatibility. Even though my GPU is ostensibly compatible, when I bailed and tried installing Tensorflow CPU it went off without a hitch.

Comment: What version are you trying to install ? TF 1.2 has dropped Mac GPU support as per https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.2.0-rc1

Answer (score 0):

You must install both CUDA 7.5 and 8.0, CuDNN 5 and 6, CUDA 7.5 installation will fail, but it's fine. If you didn't install any of them, do it now.